# How to compare two arrays of arrays 'array-elementwise' in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Given two arrays of arrays A and B, I need to test the equality of each subarray from A (ai) to its corresponding subarray in B (bi):

```
import numpy as np

a1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
a2 = np.array([3, 4, 5])
a3 = np.array([2, 4, 6])
A = np.array([a1, a2, a3])

b1 = np.array([3, 2, 1])
b2 = np.array([3, 4, 5])
b3 = np.array([6, 4, 2])
B = np.array([b1, b2, b3])

def compare_arrays(A, B):
    #ret = A == B
    #ret = np.array_equal(A, B)
    return ret

print(compare_arrays(A, B))
```

Unsurprisingly, the output I get with `A == B`: `[[False  True False][ True  True  True][False  True False]]`.

Unsurprisingly, the output I get with `np.array_equal(A, B)`: `False`.

The output I would like to get: `[[False, True, False]]`.

I would like to know if there exists an off-the-shelf solution that I have not found or if I should implement my own.

Comment: I guess I could just consider the difference matrix and look for zero rows...

Comment: Even though you construct `A` from arrays, the result is a 2d array.  That's what you get from `A==B`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get logical and results along axis=1 from A == B.

```
def compare_arrays(A, B):
    ret = np.equal(A, B).all(axis=1)
    return ret
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this:

```
def compare_arrays(A, B):
    return map(lambda item: not False in item, A==B)
```

Comment: Using `map` doesn't use the power of `numpy`.

Comment: `map` loops over the rows of `A==B`.  `not False in item` is better expressed as `all(item)`.  `[all(row) for row in A==B]` is a clearer version of this approach.